# Nodejs - Waiting for a variable: Callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I understand that using callbacks will mean that the function will wait until a result has been returned before returning the result but what if I want to execute further code?

Below is an example of what I am trying to execute. `isAvailable` checks if someone has a sufficient balance in their account and returns true if they can withdraw their money.

My problem is that this function executes asynchronously so it doesn't wait for the balance to be returned before the if statement is executed.Should I separate the if statement to another function and use a callback to wait for the balance? If so, how would I do so?

```
function isAvailable(user, withdrawal, callback) {
  var balance = getBalance(user, callback);
  if (withdrawal > balance) {
    callback(false);
  } else if (withdrawal < balance) {
    callback(true);
  } 
}
```

Comment: *"My problem is that this function executes asynchronously so it doesn't wait for the balance to be returned before the if statement is executed"* i have a sneaky suspicion that getBalance doesn't return a balance period. X/Y problem.

Comment: getBalance is tried and tested, it works :)

Comment: **prove it.** :) it can't possibly return a value that doesn't exist when it returns.

Comment: Why can't it...?

Comment: because it returns immediately. it can't "wait" for the value to exist, that simply isn't possible in javascript outside of an async function (which your function is not)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ZNYCWjH5 Here is the code for my getBalance, could you explain further?

Comment: readFileSync, that's not asynchronous. that function has no need for a callback and can directly return the value. you just chose not to. however, it would be better to not use readFileSync. that's going to stop your thread (the same thread being used by all request to the server, thus pausing all requests)

Comment: Ah right, what would you suggest I use? just readfile? Like so  fs.readFile('account.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  if(err) return console.log(err);
  callback(data);
 });

Comment: bergi's answer demonstrates how the function would be used once it is properly using readFile.

Comment: i don't see a reason for having `Balance =`

Comment: Okay, I will attempt that now. I added Balance = as I was in a rush to reply

Comment: So I have made the readfile asynchronous https://pastebin.com/3dtvpSNu but applying Bergi's code and the function will still callback null

Comment: how is that possible? if anything it'd be undefined in the case of error or user doesn't exist, not null. Unless you meant `undefined`, in which case you need to investigate further.

Comment: It is definitely returning null

Comment: Then you need to trace where that null value is coming from. It isn't coming from the code provided, it must be in the data that way.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I needed to access the value in the JSON. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand that using callbacks will mean that the function will wait until a result has been returned before returning the result

No. Being asynchronous means that they return (nothing) immediately, but later call the callback function with the result.

In your example, you'll get the `balance` not as the return value of `getBalance`, but as the argument to the call to the callback function that you should pass as the second argument:

```
getBalance(user, function(balance) {
    …
});
```

Inside there, you will place the further code to execute:

```
function isAvailable(user, withdrawal, callback) {
    getBalance(user, function(balance) {
        if (withdrawal > balance) {
            callback(false);
        } else if (withdrawal < balance) {
            callback(true);
        } else { // if (withdrawal == balance)
            callback(null); // don't forget this
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ah right, thank you. I've applied the code you wrote but now it just returns null. Any idea why?

Comment: @Sprout What do you mean by "returns"? The callback might be called with `null`, the `isAvailable` function always returns `undefined` (not `null`). How were you calling it?

Comment: the callback returns null when isAvailable is called. I call it using a user, amount and function but it callback null. I thought calling back null was a safety net?

Comment: That means that `withdrawal` was neither larger nor smaller than `balance`. I don't know what `getBalance` actually does and what values you were calling it with, the code in the callback should be your business logic that only you can decide whether it is correct or not.

Comment: The withdrawal was 120 and the balance 100, so this is not the case. getBalance will callback a balance from a json file.

Comment: Then your callback will have been called with `false`. If you need further help with this, please provide a [mcve], preferably in a new question.

Comment: Solved now Bergi, I wasn't accessing the data correctly. Thank you!